# Python: an iteration over a non-empty list with no if-clause comes up empty. Why?

Tags: python, iterator, generator, leaky-abstraction

How can an iterator over a non-empty sequence, with no filtering and no aggregation (`sum()`, etc.), yield nothing?

Consider a simple example:

```
sequence = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list((el, ord(el)) for el in sequence)
```

This yields `[('a', 97), ('b', 98), ('c', 99)]` as expected.

Now, just swap the `ord(el)` out for an expression that takes the first value out of some generator using `(...).next()` — forgive the contrived example:

```
def odd_integers_up_to_length(str):
    return (x for x in xrange(len(str)) if x%2==1)

list((el, odd_integers_up_to_length(el).next()) for el in sequence)
```

This yields `[]`. Yeah, empty list. No `('a',`stuff`)` tuples. Nothing.

But we're not filtering or aggregating or reducing. A generator expression over `n` objects without filtering or aggregation must yield `n` objects, right? What's going on?

Comment: Wow... you related to hekevintran (http://stackoverflow.com/users/84952/hekevintran) at all? Ask a question. Answer it yourself almost immediately.

Comment: Is that a Bad Thing To Do? I was just sharing my observation in question form, as per <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/faq">the FAQ</a>: “It's also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own programming question, but pretend you're on Jeopardy: phrase it in the form of a question.”

Comment: My n00b warts are showing :) ... that link should be http://stackoverflow.com/faq of course

Comment: There's some debate over that FAQ entry. Yes, by all means, answer your own question. But if you routinely have a set of pre-baked questions and answers, then this site just becomes a blog, rather than an exchange. You have the misfortune of picking a day when someone abused the spirit of that FAQ.

Comment: Jarret: ah, didn't know, thanks. No such routine intended.

S. Lott: can't tell if you're being curt or just concise. If the former, save it for the FAQ authors. I was acting in good faith here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`odd_integers_up_to_length(el).next()` will raise StopIteration, which isn't caught there, but is caught for the generator expression within it, stopping it without ever yielding anything.

look at the first iteration, when the value is 'a':

```
>>> odd_integers_up_to_length('a').next()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

Comment: Oops, I should have stated that I was just posting an observation in the form of a question — sorry I took your time needlessly!

Answer (score 4):

What happens is that the `next()` call raises a `StopIteration` exception, which bubbles up the stack to the outer generator expression and stops *that* iteration.

A `StopIteration` is the normal way for an iterator to signal that it's done. Generally we don't see it, because generally the `next()` call occurs within a construct that consumes the iterator, e.g. `for x in iterator` or `sum(iterator)`. But when we call `next()` directly, we are the ones responsible for catching the `StopIteration`. Not doing so springs a leak in the abstraction, which here leads to unexpected behavior in the outer iteration.

The lesson, I suppose: be careful about direct calls to `next()`.

Answer (score 0):

str is a reserved keword, you should name your variable differently

I was also to advise about the next

Comment: True :), this was just thrown together for the example here.

Comment: Terminology nitpick: not a reserved keyword (or it wouldn't compile) - it's a builtin, which it is good practice not to shadow.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> seq=['a','b','c']
>>> list((el,4) for el in seq)
[('a',4), ('b',4), ('c',4)]
```

So it's not `list` giving you trouble here...